# Spring: How does method getBean(String...) find the bean based on an input string?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following code that work well:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DiDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(DiDemoApplication.class, args);
        MyController controller = (MyController) ctx.getBean("myController");
        controller.hello();
    }
}

@Controller
public class MyController {

    public String hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

I removed the import's statements. This code runs and prints "Hello World".

My question regards the line:

```
MyController controller = (MyController) ctx.getBean("myController");
```

I understand the the code looks for a controller that is associated with the string "myController". However, I don't see how the class MyController is linked to any kind of such a string. How does Spring map the class name MyController to the string "myController"? It's not even the same name (the letter 'm' is not case sensitive in both cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will find it because you haven't specified an explicit name, and by default Spring will use the class name but starting with a lowercase letter to create the beans you have annotated with @Controller, @Resource and so on. See the documentation for details:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.x/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-beanname

If you name your @Controller ( @Controller(value="myBean"), or simply @Controller("myBean") ) you would need to use that name when you get the bean from the context.

Comment: I tried to use @Controller(name="myBean") and I got error:
"cannot find symbol name"

Comment: oh, try without the name part, might be value that is the default field name ( @Controller(value="myBean") ? Should also work with @Controller("myBean") (I don't have a running Java/Spring environment in front of me  :(

Comment: Works for value. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you annotate any class with an annotation which extends from `@Component` annotation (`@Controller` extends from `@Component`), Spring will load it to its ApplicationContext if that class falls within the Component Scan Scope.

Spring will load that component and name it similar to the Class name but in Camel Casing (Camel Casing is used to name any variable in Java) and thus in this case `myController`.

Comment: You type faster ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It´s a kind of mapping which is preset for you application, because you map it in the configuration like this:

```
<bean id="myClass" class="MyClass">...</bean>
```

It´s working because the ApplicationContext is Part of Spring-IoT which is representing the beans. It´s a Container for beans and their configurations and to naming is clear.

Be careful with calls like this because implementations could be changed but keep the same name and then you get a crash at your runtime.
The safer way would be a own setter which is type-safe:

```
public void setMyClass(MyClass myClass) {
   this.myClass = myClass;
}

// CONFIG
<bean id="myClass" class="MyClass">...</bean>
<bean id="myOtherClass" class="MyOtherClass">
   <property name="myClass" ref="myClass"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: The codebase I was talking about had no config file.